# Glance icon size for watchOS?

Tags: icons, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-glances

I'm trying to use one of the Glance templates and placing my image in the upper left corner. The problem is that my icon is showing up fuzzy.

The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/) doesn't specify the size of what this icon should be. Any ideas on what the `1x`, `2x`, and `3x` sizes should be for this Glance template?

Also, do I drag and image control there or do I just set that section's background image to my icon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloadable templates containing details of the glance image sizes can be found in the [Resources section](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/resources/) of that Apple Watch HIG document, under Templates.

- [Photoshop templates](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/iOS/Apple_Watch__Design_Resources/Templates.zip)
- [Sketch templates](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/iOS/Apple_Watch__Design_Resources/Templates__Sketch.zip)

The Group Left Small image size should be 30@2x (38mm) or 33.5@2x (42mm). watchOS wouldn't need 1x or 3x image sizes.

The necessary controls are already provided by the template. As you mentioned, you'd simply set that group's background image to be your icon.